# How to set up NetBeans to use Google Play Services

Tags: netbeans, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to set up an android project with NetBeans using nbandroid that uses Google Cloud Messaging. I already searched plenty of tutorials on this, but something is still missing.
I installed nbandroid just fine, and allready tested that i can create projects, debug and run it on emulators and even on a live device.

But when i want to import the google play libraries NetBeans simply does not find them. I installed Google APIs for my targeted android version and also the google play service under extras in the SDK Manager of nbandroid, but NetBeans still does not find them.

I tried adding a library to the android project, but nbandroid does not allow adding extra libraries that are not other NetBeans projects.

I simply cant import the classes, so i guess NetBeans cant find the needed jar files, but i can't figure out how to configure the project, so that it uses those libraries.

Edit:

It seems that copying the jar from `android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs` to the lib folder of the project works. But is this the proper way ?

Comment: What google library are you trying to use?  You should be using Smack API for xmpp.  google has deprecated their libraries.

Comment: The one that gets installed from the Android SDK manager.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I can't help.  I am more server side than I am android.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing Android Apps using netbeans and I had the same issue with you. The only way to add google play services is to add the .jar files in your project.

You can find the jars on my github repository https://github.com/nsiatras/Google-Play-Firebase-jars